# How to run Azure CLI run-command invoke with a PowerShell Script file with more that one parameter in Python?

Tags: python, azure-cli

I managed to run my script with just one parameter and it works:

`from subprocess import call`

```
call(["az", "vm", "run-command", "invoke", "--command-id", "RunPowerShellScript", "-n", "NONPROD-AA-1", "-g", "NONPROD_APP_RG", "--scripts", "@test.ps1", "--parameters", "pattern=test"])
```

But when I tried to send two parameters it fails:
I tried so many ways like these:

```
call(["az", "vm", "run-command", "invoke", "--command-id", "RunPowerShellScript", "-n", "NONPROD-AA-0", "-g", "NONPROD_APP_RG", "--scripts", "@test.ps1", "--parameters", "pattern=test pattern2=test2"])
```

```
call(["az", "vm", "run-command", "invoke", "--command-id", "RunPowerShellScript", "-n", "NONPROD-BIZ-0", "-g", "NONPROD_APP_RG", "--scripts", "@test.ps1", "--parameters", "pattern=test,pattern2=test2"])
```

```
call(["az", "vm", "run-command", "invoke", "--command-id", "RunPowerShellScript", "-n", "NONPROD-BIZ-0", "-g", "NONPROD_APP_RG", "--scripts", "@test.ps1", "--parameters", "@(pattern=test,pattern2=test2"])
```

All of them fails.

Any idea???

Thanks !!!

Update:

I managed to send more than one parameter like this:

```
call(["az", "vm", "run-command", "invoke", "--command-id", "RunPowerShellScript", "-n", "NONPROD-AA-0", "-g", "NONPROD_APP_RG", "--scripts", "@test.ps1", "--parameters", "pattern=test" "test2"])
```

"...--parameters", "pattern=test" "test2"])

I just have to specify the first param name with its value, then the rest of params values without the name of it. It is weird, but it works.

Comment: Could you please tell me the error? Besides, could you please tell me if you can run the command in Azure Clound Shell

Comment: I update the main post.

Comment: Now I ran into another problem when passing a path as a parameter:                        
txt = "pathFile=" + R"G:\Accela\av.web\conf\av\serverConfig.properties"     =                                pathFile=G:\Accela\av.web\conf\av\serverConfig.properties.                                                      If I pass the parameter as                                                                             
"pathFile=" + R"G:\Accela\av.web\conf\av\serverConfig.properties" it coverted to "G:\\Accela\\av.web\\conf\\av\\serverConfig.properties".